# Python ProcessPoolExecutor with conditions

Tags: python, multiprocessing, conditional-statements, enumerate, concurrent.futures

I have to process a large amount of image data and would like to use the `.map()` function from the `concurrent.futures` package to speed it up. The goal is to loop over all the images in a directory, process them, and then save them in another directory. This in itself is not a problem but I would like to save 90% of the processed images in one directory and the remaining 10% in another directory. How can I do this using `.map()`?

Without `.map()` I enumerate the images and then say:

```
if enumerator < (len(directory) * 0.9):
     save image in one directory
else:
     save image in another directory
```

How can I add this to the function I call with `.map()`, since I don't have access to the enumerator anymore?

Any help is very much appreciated!

All the best,
snowe

Comment: Could you include a little bit more code, especially what you did to create your `concurrent.futures` object and how you call its `map` method. It makes helping you easier ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use additional arguments to the map function, these arguments should be iterators, 1 element from each iterator will be passed to each iteration your job pool goes through:

```py
def my_function(file, sorting_bool):
  if sorting_bool:
    # do this with `file`
  else:
    # do that with `file`

total = len(directory)
sorter = lambda x: x < 0.9 * total
dir_sorted = map(sorter, range(total))
pool.map(my_function, directory, dir_sorted)
```

In general for other tasks you could send a job id and total id to your job:

```py
def my_function(file, job_id, total_jobs):
  if job_id < total_jobs * 0.9:
    # Do this
  else:
    # Do that

total = len(directory)
pool.map(my_function, directory, range(total), lambda: total)
```

And then use those numbers however you'd like inside of your `my_function`

If you have an unknown number of total jobs you could still create a generator to create a counter:

```py
def counter():
  i = 0
  while True:
    yield i
    i += 1

pool.map(my_function, counter(), other, args)
```

Comment: Wow, thank you for the quick response Robin! :) I just had the idea to save each image according to a probability which seems to do the job. I guess for this simple condition it's fine but your solution seems a bit more sophisticated ;)

Comment: Hah yea, a probability would do. I just hope my examples show a few of the possibilities of `map` in combination with iterators!